# value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have an application with spark MLlib-scala, I want to split my data on 3 parties: Training, test, validation. My code is the following:

```
 val training_RDD = Ratingfiles.filter(x => x._1 < 6)
      .values
      .cache()

val validation_RDD = Ratingfiles.filter(x => x._1 >= 6 && x._1 < 8)
      .values
      .cache()
```

when I compile my program with sbt compile, I have this error:

```
value _1 is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating
```

Spark-core: 1.4.1
Spark-MLlib:2.0.1
Scala version: 2.11.1
Sbt version: 0.13.12

Comment: Can you show what's the type of `Ratingfiles`?

Comment: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating] = MapPartitionsRDD[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler claims, `org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating` does not have a member called `_1` (you're probably confusing it with a Tuple, for which the members are `_1`, `_2` etc.).

`Rating` has three members:

```
case class Rating @Since("0.8.0") (
  @Since("0.8.0") user: Int,
  @Since("0.8.0") product: Int,
  @Since("0.8.0") rating: Double)
```

So - if you mean to be filtering by `user`, simply access that member instead of `_1`:

```
val training_RDD = Ratingfiles.filter(x => x.user < 6)
  .cache()

val validation_RDD = Ratingfiles.filter(x => x.user >= 6 && x.user < 8)
  .cache()
```

Comment: I splited my data into three non-overlapping subsets, based on the last digit of the parameter timestamp and it's type Long.

Comment: What? According to the compiler error, `Ratingfiles` has the type `RDD[Rating]` - which means each record is a `Rating`, which has the members listed in the answer. You say you're trying to split by "timestamp" - but `Rating` has nothing that can be thought of as timestamp... what are you expecting the RDD to contain (what _type_)?

Comment: I just splited my file into 3 parties, the new RDD must be take a Rating type. I changed x => x._1 by x => x.user it's fine but he do not accept the "values" now.

Comment: do you _need_ the `.values` now? What's the expected types of `training_RDD` and `validation_RDD`?

Comment: Because I resolved the problem of value _1. the types of training_RDD and validation_RDD are RDD[Rating].

Comment: OK - corrected my answer - just remove the `.values`

Comment: Ok, thank you, I have already deleted them, but now I have another problem. In fact when I parse my data in the beginning of my program by val Ratingfiles = sc.textFile("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/ProjetFilm/myfile.dat")..toString).map {line =>
val splitRating =  line.split("::").toString
Rating(splitRating(0).toInt, splitRating(1).toInt, splitRating(2).toDouble)
}

Comment: when I run by line of command (I lunch the spark-shell) line by ligne .    When I run this ligne: val Ratingfiles = sc.textFile("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/tmp/ProjetFilm/myfile.dat"), then I take Ratingfiles.take(4) (for example) I find my data( from myfile.dat) and when I run all the lignes and I write Ratingfiles.take(4) I find another data. May be because it take the format of Rating(MLLib of Spark).

Comment: this is a completely unrelated question - you can post a new question, I can't answer it concisely in comments. If my answer helped, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Spark Rating class have 3 attributes (since spark 0.8.0) :

- user
- product
- rating

If you want to get the first value, you need to invoke `user()`; the second value `product()`; the third value `rating()`

sources  : https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/Rating.html

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/ALS.scala